# Pandas value_counts still showing dropped value with count of 0 after dropping rows with that value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df:

```
      name_col     species_col
0     alice        cat
1     bob          cat
2     darwin       dog
3     frank        ferret
```

Made a new dataframe excluding ferrets:

```
In:

df_minus_ferrets = df.drop(df[df['species_col'].str.contains('ferret')].index)
df_minus_ferrets[df_minus_ferrets['species_col'].str.contains('ferret')]

Out:
     name_col     species_col
(empty dataframe)
```

But when I run value_counts on the new dataframe, it still shows the `ferret` value with a count of `0`.

```
In:

df_minus_ferrets['species_col'].value_counts()

Out:

cat           2
dog           1
ferret        0
Name: Day, dtype: int64
```

I'm curious as to why and how can I make it go away? Is it because this is still a view? Apologies for the formatting, first time posting here.

Comment: `species_col` is Categorical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't reproduce your code. One explanation is that your variables are [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_col': ['alice', 'bob', 'darwin', 'frank'],
                   'species_col': ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'ferret'],
                  })

df_minus_ferrets = df.drop(df[df['species_col'].str.contains('ferret')].index)

df_minus_ferrets['species_col'].value_counts()
```

output:

```
cat    2
dog    1
Name: species_col, dtype: int64
```